# Open all files in a directory using vim in reverse order

Tags: linux, vim

How do I open all the files in a given directory using vim, in the reverse alphabetical order? The command -

```
vim *
```

would open all files in alphabetical order. How can I iterate through the files using `:n` in the opposite order? I found the use of `tac` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567635/printing-files-in-reverse-order-linux), another solution here that displays the file content [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818295/looping-files-in-directory-in-reverse-order), and a solution for emacs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714735/open-two-files-in-emacs-in-reverse-order), but they are not solutions for `vim`.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea may be to reverse what `*` yields:

```
printf '%s\n' * | tac
```

and use this with `xargs` to spawn `vim`. Two problems with this:

1. In general file names may contain newline characters, so it's better to separate with null characters and use `xargs -0`.
2. `vim` spawned by `xargs` in a pipe will complain about input not being from a terminal. Strange things may happen. If your `xargs` supports `-o` (reopen stdin as `/dev/tty` in the child process before executing the command) then use it.

The whole solution then:

```
printf '%s\0' * | tac -s "" | xargs -0o vim
```

Notes:

- `tac` is not required by POSIX; `xargs` may not support the options used. The entire approach is not portable.
- Empty string as option-argument to `tac -s` seems to set null character as separator without passing any null character explicitly (it may be problematic).
- There is [`ARG_MAX` limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/10765659), you cannot run a command that is longer. If there are many files, the expansion of `*` may exceed the limit, you may get `Argument list too long`. If `printf` is a builtin in your shell then the limit may not apply at this point. Still it applies when `xargs` tries to spawn `vim`. `xargs` will detect this and run two or more `vim` processes in sequence, if needed. This, however, may not be what you want. Hopefully, since you're going to manually iterate with `:n`, I expect the number of files is not that big, so `ARG_MAX` won't be a problem.

Comment: I get an `Illegal variable name` error.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, I am using a tcsh shell.

Comment: Yes more than the type of shell, it seems to be a problem with the quotes

Comment: `printf '%s\n' * | tac` reverses the order, but `printf '%s\n' * | tac -s "\0"` does not.

Comment: @V-Red The command in the current version of my answer works for me in `tcsh`.